# Avoiding mirrors to install a freshly released gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Bundler 1.3.0 has just been released ([only 10 people](https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler) have installed it so far), but I can only install a pre version, or a previous version.

```
$ gem install bundler --version 1.3.0 --verbose
HEAD http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (= 1.3.0) in any repository
HEAD http://rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD http://production.s3.rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: bundler

$ gem install bundler --version 1.3.0 --clear-sources --source http://rubygems.org --verbose
HEAD http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (= 1.3.0) in any repository
HEAD http://rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD http://production.s3.rubygems.org/prerelease_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: bundler

$ gem install bundler --verbose
HEAD http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
Installing gem bundler-1.2.4
/Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.2.4/.gitignore
<snip>
/Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/bundle
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.4
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.2.4
Parsing sources...
100% [100/100]  lib/bundler/vlad.rb                                             
Done installing documentation for bundler (2 sec).
1 gem installed
```

How can I tell rubygems to look at a canonical repository, rather than an out-of-date mirror?

Comment: The download is now 10,333,312 from 10 in just four hours. It is surprising. I didn't know there were so many Ruby (on Rails) users.

Comment: @sawa that's *total downloads*, i.e. all versions.

Comment: BTW, I'm facing the same problem. `gem list -r bundler` shows `bundler (1.2.4)`

Comment: @Stefan Right. I saw the wrong part. Correctly, it says 59 now.

Comment: I downloaded the gem file from https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/versions/1.3.0, and installed it with `gem install path/to/gem/file`.

Comment: Seems like the mirror has been updated, `gem list -r bundler` now shows `bundler (1.3.0)`

Comment: @Yanhao can you change that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the [gem file](http://rubygems.org/downloads/bundler-1.3.0.gem) from [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/versions/1.3.0), and installed it with `gem install path/to/gem/file`.

Somebody said that they installed it by `gem install bundler --pre`, but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Gemfile:

```
gem "nokogiri", :git => "git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git", :branch => "1.4"

git "git://github.com/wycats/thor.git", :tag => "v0.13.4"
gem "thor"
```

http://gembundler.com/git.html

Or try this gem:
https://github.com/rdp/specific_install