# Can't install bundler 1.3.0 with ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, ruby-2.0

I installed Ruby 2.0.0 and the compilation went fine but when I use `bundle install` it gives me this error:

```
Bundler is not compatible with Ruby 2.0 or Rubygems 2.0.
Please upgrade to Bundler 1.3 or higher.
```

If I try to update it with `gem update bundler`:

```
$ gem update bundler
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

And when I try to update RubyGems:

```
$ gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
```

What am I missing?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0-p0 & RVM 1.18.14.

Comment: Yanhao's comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061975/avoiding-mirrors-to-install-a-freshly-released-gem provided a good workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bundler 1.3 hasn’t been released yet, until it is you must install the prerelease version:

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

Comment: They should really add this in the warning.

Comment: Thanks! Good to note that I had to update my Gemfile to use `source "http://rubygems.org"` instead of `source :rubygems`... There seems to be a problem with https too.

Comment: @VincentB. Should specify your source as HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: Tried and got an SSL error. I will post it when I get the occasion.